# Vue 3 Composition API - Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am using **Vue 3 Composition api** with **Typescript** to implement pinch zoom using [HammerJS package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hammerjs).

I am trying to follow a working example written in JavaScript from **CodePen**: https://codepen.io/bakho/details/GBzvbB to implement in Vue.

However, I ran into some issues when trying to make it work in my Vue application which I am not sure how to solve it.

**Here are the following errors:**

```
// Object is possibly 'null'.
imageContainer.value.offsetWidth;

// Object is possibly 'null'.
imageContainer.value.appendChild(displayImage);

// Object is possibly 'null'.
imageContainer.value.addEventListener...
```

**Here is the full source code:**

```
<template>
  <h1>Image Zoom</h1>
  <div class="imageContainer" ref="imageContainer"></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Hammer from "hammerjs";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const imageUrl = "https://source.unsplash.com/random";
    const imageContainer = ref(null)

    let minScale = 1; let maxScale = 4; let imageWidth : any; let imageHeight : any; let containerWidth : any;
    let containerHeight : any; let displayImageX = 0; let displayImageY = 0; let displayImageScale = 1;
    let displayDefaultWidth : any; let displayDefaultHeight 
    let rangeX = 0; let rangeMaxX = 0; let rangeMinX = 0;
    let rangeY = 0; let rangeMaxY = 0; let rangeMinY = 0;

    // let displayImageRangeY = 0;

    let displayImageCurrentX = 0;
    let displayImageCurrentY = 0;
    let displayImageCurrentScale = 1;

    function resizeContainer() {
      containerWidth = imageContainer.value.offsetWidth;
      containerHeight = imageContainer.value.offsetHeight;
      if (displayDefaultWidth !== undefined && displayDefaultHeight !== undefined) {
        displayDefaultWidth = displayImage.offsetWidth;
        displayDefaultHeight = displayImage.offsetHeight;
        updateRange();
        displayImageCurrentX = clamp(displayImageX, rangeMinX, rangeMaxX);
        displayImageCurrentY = clamp(displayImageY, rangeMinY, rangeMaxY);
        updateDisplayImage(
          displayImageCurrentX,
          displayImageCurrentY,
          displayImageCurrentScale
        );
      }
    }
    resizeContainer();

    function clamp(value, min, max) {
      return Math.min(Math.max(min, value), max);
    }

    function clampScale(newScale) {
      return clamp(newScale, minScale, maxScale);
    }

    const displayImage = new Image();
        displayImage.src = imageUrl;
        displayImage.onload = function(){
        imageWidth = displayImage.width;
        imageHeight = displayImage.height;
        imageContainer.value.appendChild(displayImage);
        displayImage.addEventListener('mousedown', e => e.preventDefault(), false);
        displayDefaultWidth = displayImage.offsetWidth;
        displayDefaultHeight = displayImage.offsetHeight;
        rangeX = Math.max(0, displayDefaultWidth - containerWidth);
        rangeY = Math.max(0, displayDefaultHeight - containerHeight);
    }

    imageContainer.value.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
        displayImageScale = displayImageCurrentScale = clampScale(displayImageScale + (e.wheelDelta / 800));
        updateRange();
        displayImageCurrentX = clamp(displayImageCurrentX, rangeMinX, rangeMaxX)
        displayImageCurrentY = clamp(displayImageCurrentY, rangeMinY, rangeMaxY)
        updateDisplayImage(displayImageCurrentX, displayImageCurrentY, displayImageScale);  
    }, false);

    function updateDisplayImage(x, y, scale) {
        const transform = 'translateX(' + x + 'px) translateY(' + y + 'px) translateZ(0px) scale(' + scale + ',' + scale + ')';
        displayImage.style.transform = transform;
        displayImage.style.webkitTransform = transform;
        displayImage.style.transform = transform;
    }

    function updateRange() {
        rangeX = Math.max(0, Math.round(displayDefaultWidth * displayImageCurrentScale) - containerWidth);
        rangeY = Math.max(0, Math.round(displayDefaultHeight * displayImageCurrentScale) - containerHeight);
        
        rangeMaxX = Math.round(rangeX / 2);
        rangeMinX = 0 - rangeMaxX;

        rangeMaxY = Math.round(rangeY / 2);
        rangeMinY = 0 - rangeMaxY;
    }

    const hammertime = new Hammer(imageContainer);
    hammertime.get('pinch').set({ enable: true });
    hammertime.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });

    hammertime.on('pan', ev => {  
        displayImageCurrentX = clamp(displayImageX + ev.deltaX, rangeMinX, rangeMaxX);
        displayImageCurrentY = clamp(displayImageY + ev.deltaY, rangeMinY, rangeMaxY);
        updateDisplayImage(displayImageCurrentX, displayImageCurrentY, displayImageScale);
    });

    hammertime.on('pinch pinchmove', ev => {
        displayImageCurrentScale = clampScale(ev.scale * displayImageScale);
        updateRange();
        displayImageCurrentX = clamp(displayImageX + ev.deltaX, rangeMinX, rangeMaxX);
        displayImageCurrentY = clamp(displayImageY + ev.deltaY, rangeMinY, rangeMaxY);
        updateDisplayImage(displayImageCurrentX, displayImageCurrentY, displayImageCurrentScale);
    });

    hammertime.on('panend pancancel pinchend pinchcancel', () => {
        displayImageScale = displayImageCurrentScale;
        displayImageX = displayImageCurrentX;
        displayImageY = displayImageCurrentY;
    }); 

    return {};
  },
});
</script>

<style>
.imageContainer {
  width: 96%;
  height: 96%;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #2b2b2c;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.imageContainer > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  cursor: move;
  touch-action: none;
}
</style>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong and why is it causes this `Object is possibly 'null'`

Comment: `const imageContainer = ref(null)`. This is your declaration, you declare it as `null`, that's why it can be null.

Comment: Even if I were to replace `const imageContainer = ref(null)`, with `const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.imageContainer')`, I have still having the same exact error.

Comment: You should probably not use a querySelector tbh, but rather `template $refs`.

Comment: which is exactly why i created `ref="imageContainer"` and thus the error `Object is possibly 'null'`.

Answer (score 0):

So this are the reasons for that error:

- `const imageContainer = ref(null)` -> you set the value to be `null` and TypeScript is warning you that any access to properties of that object can throw an error because initial value is `null` and also since you are trying to use `ref` in template that element can exist or it does not have to exist.
- `const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.imageContainer')` -> you are querying for HTML element that exists or does not exist, that means you can also get `null` as a value and TypeScript is again warning you that any access to properties of that object can throw an error

Solution:

- you have to actually return `imageContainer` variable from `setup` function so that Vue bindes it with `ref` in template and have any access to that variable be inside of `onMounted` function since it's a `ref` which means it's not yet mounted in to the DOM. `setup` is called before `created` and `mounted` hook in Vue.js component lifecycle and you don't have access to any DOM stuff there.

```js
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const imageContainer = ref(null)

    onMounted(() => {
      // here you access imageContainer variable
    })

    return {
      imageContainer 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it still does not work. Having the same `Object is possibly 'null'` error.

Comment: I updated the answer tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

This is a Typescript error. The issue is that you're not handling the possibility of the variable being null. All you need to do is properly define the type and handle the null case. Have a read of [Typing `ref`](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-ref) from the Vue docs to see what I mean.

Here's some examples for your case:

```js
// Define the ref as an HTMLElement or null
const imageContainer = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);

...

// Set the width/height based on the imageContainer, or use 0 if it is null.
containerWidth = imageContainer.value?.offsetWidth ?? 0;
containerHeight = imageContainer.value?.offsetHeight ?? 0;

...

// Only call appendChild/addEventListener if the ref is not null.
imageContainer.value?.appendChild(displayImage);
```

If you apply this approach wherever the error appears, this should take care of the issue.